# Изменить значение переменной по клику

Tags: php, javascript

Есть форма с post запросом. Сперва хотел бы сделать кнопку неактивной или по нажатию вывести сообщение об ошибке.

```
<form action="out.php" method="post">
<p>Укажите вашу ссылку: <input type="text" name="longurl" value="ссылка" /></p> 
<p>Описание: <input type="text" name="comment" value="описание" /></p> 
<input type="submit" name="button" value="OK">
</form>
```

И ниже вывожу некоторые записи из бд (текст - гиперссылка)

```
<?php echo $row['comment']?>  <a href="<?php echo $row['url']?>"> Посетить </a>
```

Мне нужно,что бы по какому-то количеству нажатий на гиперссылки кнопка стала доступной или высветилась надпись о доступности кнопки.

Скажите, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

поменяйте

```
<input type="submit" name="button" value="OK">
```

на

```
<button id="my_button" disabled onclick="clickOkButton();">OK</button>
```

добавьте в тэг form свойство name="myForm"

Где нибудь ниже этой кнопки вставьте

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var counter = 10;
    function clickOkButton(){
        counter--;
        if(counter>0) return;
        if(counter == 0){
            document.getElementById('my_button').disabled = false;
            return;
        }
        document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

PS писал с ходу, могут быть синтаксические ошибки, но идея должна быть понятна.

Comment: чуть-чуть не ясна. Могу ли я как-то в нужном мне месте изменить counter?